# 2007 Honda Civic Coupe won't crank

Tags: honda, starting, civic

Hey so I have this 2007 civic coupe and when I try to start the car it doesnt click at all.  The dash lights come on and that's about it.  The battery light, oil pressure light, and a small green key light all come on if I try to start the car.  I have no oil leaks, no engine cracks as far as I can tell, the battery is fully charged and I've had the oil changed in the past 2 months.  Like I said I can try to turn the ignition but only the dash lights and the following warning lights appear.  The car doesn't click when I turn the ignition either.  Ive heard it could be the alternator, the starter, or the anti-theft system in the car.  Any help?

Comment: If the green key is on and stays on without *any* type of noise from the starter, the problem is most likely the anti-theft system having an issue. Either it doesn't recognize the key or it's broke (the receiver ring is not working right). You may try a separate key to see if it works. If not, you will probably want to get the receiver ring replaced. (Most vehicles have this around the ignition switch.)

Comment: @ᴘᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 If the immobilizer is blocking cranking on a Honda the green key blinks. In normal operation it comes on for a few seconds at key on and then goes off.

Answer (score 2):

The most common cause of no crank on this model is starter failure. When this starter fails it is unlikely to make any noise unlike the older designs that had a different solenoid design. The older types made a loud click from the starter.

If the dash lights stay on bright during a crank attempt the starter and alternator are OK. The lights should dim a little, but not dim way down or go out, during cranking.

If the immobilizer is blocking cranking on a Honda the green key blinks. In normal operation it comes on for a few seconds at key on and then goes off. So this system is not likely to be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If no clicks heard from under the bonnet, it could be easily starter solenoid is stuck. In some cases, it could help if you throw few knocks on the solenoid with a stick like hammer handle, this could free up the solenoid and your car would crank again.

Comment: You can't do this on that gen Civic, the starter is buried under the intake manifold.